# Characterizing isotropic measures

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, measure-theory, euclidean-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

A Borel measure $\mu$ on $S^{n-1}$ is called isotropic if $$\int_{S^{n-1}}
\langle \theta, x \rangle^2 d\mu(x)=\frac{\mu\left({S^{n-1}}\right)}{n}$$ for all $\theta\in S^{n-1}$.

This means that in some sense the measure is "evenly distributed" on the sphere, but I'm wondering if one can give more explicit characterizations of such measures, or some geometric intuition, possibly in terms of the support. For instance, an isotropic measure cannot be supported on a subset of a proper subspace, because then there is some $\theta$ for which the integral vanishes. Are there other such simple necessary conditions?

Some examples are also useful: for instance, the Lebesgue measure is isotropic. On $S^1$ it can be shown with some trigonometry that a discrete uniform measure on the points $\textrm{exp}\left(\frac{\pi i j}{k}\right)$ is isotropic. These examples give an idea of the "even distribution" of these measures (and their support), but I'm really hoping more can be said.  For instance, is there a similar set of discrete isotropic measures in higher dimensions? How can we show this? How about other (discrete) uniform measures? etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take an orthonormal basis $E=\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ on the sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$, the measure 
$$\mu=\sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{e_i}$$
is isotropic, because the integral gives $|\theta|^2$, and so is any finite linear combination of such measures obtained by different o.n. bases.

You can also consider an integral average of $\mu$. If $\Theta$ is a probability on the space of rotations $O(n)$, you can define
$$\mu_\Theta =\int\limits_{O(n)}(T_\sharp \mu)d\Theta(T)$$
where $T_\sharp \mu$ is the pushforward measure given by $T_\sharp \mu(A)=\mu(T^{-1}(A))$. Then
\begin{align}
\int\limits_{\mathcal{S}^{n-1}}\langle \theta,x\rangle^2d\mu_\Theta(x)&= \int_{O(n)}d\Theta(T)\int\limits_{\mathcal{S}^{n-1}}\langle \theta,x\rangle^2dT_\sharp\mu(x)= \\
&=\int_{O(n)}d\Theta(T)\int\limits_{\mathcal{S}^{n-1}}\langle \theta,T^{-1}x\rangle^2d\mu(x)\\
&=\int_{O(n)}d\Theta(T)\int\limits_{\mathcal{S}^{n-1}}\langle T\theta,x\rangle^2d\mu(x)\\
&=\frac{\mu(\mathcal{S}^{n-1})}{n}=\frac{\mu_\Theta(\mathcal{S}^{n-1})}{n}
\end{align}
so $\mu_\Theta$ is isotropic, and this works starting from any isotropic $\mu$.

Comment: Thanks! I was also thinking of these type of measures, but wasn't sure how to formalize them

Comment: I was thinking about the discrete measure associated to the vertices of a polyhedron, or polytope in higher dimensions. Is it isotropic? Even in 3D I don't find simple arguments to tell

Comment: Of course not all polyhedrons will satisfy this. But John's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_ellipsoid) might help

Comment: Sure, in fact I really meant to say _regular_ polyhedra. If I'm not mistaken any regular simplex or cube in any dimension is isotropic in the sense above, using the explicit coordinates of vertices. If it were true for all regular polytopes in any dimension I strongly believe there would be a simple argument about Lie groups and Haar measure on $SO(n)$ that would prove it, but I'm too rusty on the subject right now. Anyway I knew John's theorem but not the characterization due to Ball, very interesting

Comment: I just realized there's a simple way to prove it in 3D: you can view the vertices of every regular polyhedron as the union of vertices of suitable rotated tetrahedra: for example http://blogs.ams.org/visualinsight/2015/05/15/dodecahedron-with-5-tetrahedra/. So by linearity and by the fact that the tetrahedron is isotropic, the same holds for every polyhedron.

Answer (score 1):

One way to obtain such isotropic measures, at least on $S^2$ and probably on higher-dimensional spheres up to some topological identifications, is the following, where I always take $n=3$.

On the $2$-torus there are plenty measures with the "uniform" distribution that you describe: for example take any translation with irrational slope. Then you can project this to the sphere by taking a branched cover (with four branch points). As far as I understand the induced measure will have the property that you want.